# Convert/Serialize to JSON based on schema

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

When serializing XML to JSON the complex types are lost - everything becomes string.

**How to convert XML to JSON or JSON to JSON based on a JSON/XSD schema to retain complex types?**

- The schema would be predefined in a file and loaded on runtime.
  Object structure based on classes can not be used.
- JSON.NET / Newtonsoft implementation would be preferred but is not required.

*Duplicate response: I cannot find how to use a schema definition which will result in strongly typed JSON conversion in any of the proposed duplicates.*

Comment: Here is good explanation : https://codepunk.io/xml-vs-json-why-json-sucks/

Comment: Grigoris: Can you tell me where they explain how to use a predefined XSD/JSON schema which can be loaded from a file on runtime?